# Global Variables in Embedded C

Tags: c, freertos

In Embedded C, using variables in different units and in different threads is proving tricky. Here's an example in FreeRTOS...

### Existing Code

**app_main.c**

```
#include "global.h"
#include <freertos/FreeRTOS.h>
#include <freertos/task.h>
#include <freertos/event_groups.h>
#include <freertos/semphr.h>
#include <freertos/queue.h>
xQueueHandle xMailbox_lux   = {0};

app_main() {
    ...
    xMailbox_lux = xQueueCreate( 1, sizeof( xMailboxData_t ) );
```

**global.h**

```
extern xQueueHandle xMailbox_lux;
```

**files where xMailbox_lux is used (read in 3 files. Written in only 1)**

```
#include <global.h>
xQueueOverwrite(xMailbox_lux, &mailBoxData); // Writes
xQueuePeek(xMailbox_lux, &mailBoxStash, 0 ); // Reads
```

This code works as far as I can tell. But, is this "right"? Or is there a preferable solution using setter / getter functions? Such as:

### Setter / Getter

**app_main.c**

```
app_main() {
    ...
    xMailbox_lux = xQueueCreate( 1, sizeof( xMailboxData_t ) );
```

**global.h**

```
int set_xMailbox_lux(xQueueHandle mailbox);
xQueueHandle get_xMailbox_lux(void);
```

**global.c**

```
static xQueueHandle xMailbox_lux;

int set_xMailbox_lux(xQueueHandle mailbox) {
    xQueueOverwrite(mailbox, &xMailbox_lux);
    return 0;
}

xQueueHandle get_xMailbox_lux(void) {
    // xQueuePeek(xMailbox_lux, mailbox, 0 );
    return xMailbox_lux;
}
```

**files that Read**

```
#include <global.h>
set_xMailbox_lux(kdataMailbox);
mailBoxStash = get_xMailbox_lux();
```

And what about thread safety? Is there a best practise for thread safety? Ignoring the FreeRTOS types and queues in this example, if you are just using int types, is the setter / getter approach thread safe where the write and read are in different threads. Is there any difference as opposed to using first approach.

N.B. The second piece of code doesn't work. Get a panic each time it comes across

```
xQueuePeek( get_xMailbox_lux(), &mailBoxStash, 0 );
```

But hopefully it doesn't detract from the question.

Comment: Unless the xQueuehandle type handles thread safety for you then without seeing a lot more code no one will be able to tell you if it is thread safe - we don't know how many threads you have or what they are doing.

Comment: With the getter/setter approach you can build thread safety in fairly easily. Assuming xQueueHandle  is "dumb" and not thread safe,I'd probably have my own QueueHandle class that is a thread safe wrapper around xQueueHandle

Comment: And if we were dealing with integers, is either approach better than the other?